# 'amplify init' keeps failing

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify

I recently got myself a new PC(Predator Helios 300) and I wanted to start using aws there but when I try to perform `amplify init` I get the error below even though I already did all the other steps such as configuration.

```
× Root stack creation failed
init failed
{ SignatureDoesNotMatch: Signature expired: 20190427T235724Z is now earlier than 20190428T094952Z (20190428T095452Z - 5 min.)
    at Request.extractError (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\protocol\query.js:50:29)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:683:14)
    at Request.transition (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:14:12)
    at C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\request.js:685:12)
    at Request.callListeners (C:\Users\sahve\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@aws-amplify\cli\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:116:18)
  message:
   'Signature expired: 20190427T235724Z is now earlier than 20190428T094952Z (20190428T095452Z - 5 min.)',
  code: 'SignatureDoesNotMatch',
  time: 2019-04-27T23:57:24.753Z,
  requestId: 'ab179ef3-699b-11e9-bfe3-4ddc7ceb66ee',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: true }
```

After doing some research It seems to be a verification problem. Does anyone has experience with this or knows how to resolve this issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like your system clock might be misaligned - make sure its correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time you see an error like "is now earlier than" around some numbers that look like timestamps (`20190427T235724Z` -> `2019-04-27 23:57:24 UTC`), that's an indicator that the error is time related. Time matters for cryptography in order to validate certificates (so that an attacker cannot break a certificate and use it after its expiration, among other reasons) [1]. In this case, either your clock or the remote server clock is wrongly set. Since the remote server in this case is AWS, it is highly unlikely that they have any significant clock drift, leaving you as the possible outlier.

Given that you mentioned a new computer, it is even more likely that this is due to an incorrectly set system clock.

Reset/synchronize your system clock and the error should disappear.

---

Reference [1]: https://security.stackexchange.com/q/72866/47422