# Amplify Init - InvalidSignatureException: Signature not yet current

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, timezone, aws-amplify, ntpd

Encountered and solved this problem. Posting for posterity since my situation differed from the usual.

**Important**: I am running a derivative of Ubuntu in a VirtualBox VM on a freshly installed Windows host.

#### The Problem

When creating a new react amplify project using create-react-app, `amplify init` fails with an `InvalidSignatureException` after selecting a profile:

```
$ amplify init
...
For more information on AWS Profiles, see:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-configure-profiles.html

? Please choose the profile you want to use default

InvalidSignatureException: Signature not yet current: 20220528T081112Z is still later than 20220528T051608Z (20220528T051108Z + 5 min.)
    at Object.extractError (/snapshot/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.extractError (/snapshot/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/rest_json.js:49:8)
    at Request.callListeners (/snapshot/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/snapshot/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
...
    at IncomingMessage.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:483:12)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1241:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:84:21) {
  code: 'InvalidSignatureException',
  time: 2022-05-28T08:11:12.872Z,
  requestId: 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
  statusCode: 403,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 35.74742577991159
}
```

I also experienced errors with `amplify push` and `amplify pull` complaining about things such as "Time skew" and "Timeouts", and AWS Console threw "List apps call failed: Network Error".

#### Similar Posts

Here are a sample of posts discussing similar problems.

['amplify init' keeps failing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55893058/amplify-init-keeps-failing)

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/2014

https://github.com/concourse/s3-resource/issues/34

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2417

#### Failed ideas

Sample of failed ideas:

- I tried creating a second project to see if problem persisted. It did.
- I tried syncing my time via `ntp`, `ntpdate`, `ntpd`. Same error.
- I tried setting time via GUI. Failed to set. Same error.

##### Story leading to solution

At this point, I noticed my time occasionally jumps on sync with `ntpd`. Actual time was 01:40; on sync, it jump to 04:40, then back to 01:40. This would occur intermittently on sync. Timezones were set correctly. Trial and error exhausts my ideas, so I return to my host. Host time is 01:40, but discord messages are timestamping at 10:40. Wait.

Answer (score 1):

Windows host timezone was set to UTC-8:00 Pacific Time. VirtualBox Linux guest was set to UTC-5:00 Eastern Time. Oddly, both were displaying 01:40.

#### Steps to resolve

1. Set host timezone to UTC-5:00 Eastern Time
2. Sync Clock in "Time and Date" settings in Windows
3. Disable/uninstall `ntp` from Linux guest

Issue was resolved. `amplify init` succeeded.